# removing rows in a text file based on the occurrences of values using python or R

Tags: python, r, file, rows

I have a big text file with 32000 rows and 60 columns. (rows are genes and columns are samples and each cell contains the values of each gene in each sample). I want to remove those genes(rows) which have more than 10 times 2 and less than 2. which means for example if the first row has 2 or less than 2(gene value) in at least 10 samples(column) I want to remove it. I think at first it should iterate over the rows to find those columns which have 2 or less than 2 and count them for each row. if the count is at least 10 the row will be removed.

Comment: Have you tested the `R` code?

Comment: what are those numbers in edited version?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, you could try

```
indx <- rowSums(d1 <=2)
d1[indx <10,]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(145)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(-2:5,20*30, replace=TRUE), ncol=20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that in python (code not tested):

Assuming the files are all numbers and space separated.

```
for line in open(input_filepath, 'r'):
    values = line.split(' ')
    if len([value for value in values if float(value) <= 2]) <= 10:
        output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: thanks. this line (if len([value for values if value <= 2]) <= 10:) gives "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: now it gives: NameError: name 'output_file' is not defined

Comment: Yeah, that is just a sample incomplete code, you should define output file as follows: `output_file = open(output_filepath, 'w')`

Comment: thanks. I used this code but still there are many rows with many less-than-2 values including zero and decimals

Comment: now it gave this error:                                                        ValueError: invalid literal for float(): ENSG00000000003.10     17.83196398     69.91920499     279.89049       95.61821179     74.80702449     122.5556208     144.8049767     68.68034587     73.67798573     89.95469195     81.85856972     126.9733354     64.93879738     29.4107548      73.03579221     116.

Comment: and this is the first row

Comment: As I noted in my answer, I am assuming the file is all numbers. It seems from your input that the first value `ENSG00000000003.10` is not numeric. You should make sure that all values are numeric **and** the file is space separated.

Comment: it is space separated. but in case of non-numerics should I replace them with some numbers start from 1001 and keep the old and new columns(replacements) in a separate file and after running the codes again replace with original names?

Comment: You can skip the first column by modifying line 3 in the code to `if len([value for value in values[1:] if float(value) <= 2]) <= 10:`